# HTML Input Type Date, Open Calendar by default

Tags: html, input, calendar

I have a task which is to show the calendar by default to select date in the input field of html.

For suppose this is the code:

```
input type="date" name="bday"
```

Ok, now when I click on the input box, the calendar appears.

Tell me how to show the calendar by default without clicking on the input.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle with all your relevant code? Most likely you're handling hiding/revealing the calendar using CSS or Javascript, not pure HTML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not possible with native HTML input elements. You can use [webshim polyfill](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Forms-forms-ext), which gives you this option by using this markup.

```
<input type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
```

Here is a [small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/cc7Rt/embedded/result,html,js,css/)

Comment: I don't understand.  The demo doesn't show any calendar open by default (Chrome or Mobile Chrome/Firefox).  Are you saying there isn't any way to get trigger the "native" calendar to pop up, e.g. using an event fired from a different element?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. @Michael did you include https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/ in your project first?

Comment: downvoting because the shim is no longer being maintained by their developers so using these shims is not a recommended solution