# Is there a JavaScript method to make a html date input display the datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I would like to trigger the display of a date input's date-picker from an external button.

```
<input id="date" type="date" />
<button>display date</button>
```

For instance if I had the above code, how would I show the date-picker (the box which appears and allows you to pick a date) by clicking the button? I do not want to use jQuery or other libraries. Is there a way to show the native date-picker from an external trigger with vanilla JavaScript?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.onclick = () => {
    var input = document.querySelector("#date");
    input.showDatePicker();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Input Type Date, Open Calendar by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975667/html-input-type-date-open-calendar-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well on firefox and edge :

```html
<input id="date" type="date" />
<button>display date</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.onclick = () => {
    var input = document.querySelector("#date");
    input.focus()
    input.click()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works on Chrome/Android and Firefox/Desktop but not on Chrome/Desktop nor Firefox/Android...

Answer (score 1):

You can with

```
let x = document.getElementById('myDate'),
  d = new Date(),
  m = d.getMonth() < 10 ? `0${d.getMonth()}` : `${d.getMonth()}`,
  day = d.getDay() < 10 ? `0${d.getDay()}` : `${d.getDay()}`;

x.value = d.getFullYear() + "-" + m + "-" + day;
```

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP101ST55PX5)

Comment: Hi so I didn't want a way to get the date but a way to make the **date-picker** show. The thing that appears when you click the arrow on pc, or on mobile just touch the input. I want to make that appear from a separate button