# Display datepicker of <input type="date"> with javascript for Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input, datepicker

I'm looking for a way to show the calendar with a button just as if you clicked the drop-down arrow in the input box. Target = Chrome(65+)

[image]

There are a few questions that have addressed this but I cant get it working for the browser. Like this one:
[Is there a JavaScript method to make a html date input display the datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088264/is-there-a-javascript-method-to-make-a-html-date-input-display-the-datepicker)

Ideally, Id like the date input itself to not be visible, and the calendar widget show when the button is pressed(space is important).

```
<button type="button" onclick="openCalendar()">
    <img src="...Images/calendar.png" height="25"/></button>

<input id="datePick" type="date" style="visibility:hidden;width:0px">
```

in script:

```
function openCalendar() {
    document.getElementById('datePick').style.visibility = "visible"
    document.getElementById('datePick').focus().click() // this is the line!!
}
```

In other words, the entire input element would be replaced by a button, the value would not be shown. I would think bootstrap/jQuery unnecessary for this in chrome, anybody know? Thanks

Comment: I'll also include a function to hide the input once date has changed, unless the datepicker's visibility is independent from the input box which I doubt.

Comment: I wonder if wrapping the button in a `<label for="datePick">` would work?

Comment: Crapsnacks you are correct, I'll delete question once I find what I need from that thread, thank you for the link!!