# How to make a Font Awesome Icon launch the native browser datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a date input, and next to it I have a font awesome. How can I make the font Awesome Icon Launches the default browser datepicker?

```
<input type="date">
<span (click)="launchHereDatePicker()" class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 "></span>
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What would be that default control?

Comment: So, when you say "default browser datepicker"... are you referring to the fact that you are using a UI framework like Boostrap or jQueryUI which enhances the input fields, and you want to show the plain vanilla HTML date input field?

Comment: Similar question that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326982/open-html5-date-picker-on-icon-click?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Similar question solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326982/open-html5-date-picker-on-icon-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this works in nearly all current browsers, EXCEPT Chrome for the desktop.

#### References

- [*Is there a JavaScript method to make a html date input display the datepicker?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098854/1762224)
- [*Method to show native datepicker in Chrome*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895180/1762224)

```js
addEventListeners('.facturas', 'click', launchDatePicker);

function launchDatePicker(e) {
  let input = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  input.focus();
  input.click();
  // or you can just call this instead... openPicker(input);
}

function addEventListeners(elements, eventName, handler) {
  if (typeof elements === 'string') elements = document.querySelectorAll(elements);
  Array.from(elements).forEach(el => el.addEventListener(eventName, handler));
}

function openPicker(inputDateElement) {
  let event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  event.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, document.defaultView, 'F4', 0);
  inputDateElement.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
.facturas {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input name="some-date" type="date" />
  <span class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browser will try to focus the form control. In this case, I wrapped the icon in a label that is `for` the date element. This way the browser knows what to focus. Unfortunately, as of right now, Chrome 78 will focus the control but won't open the date picker so this is not a perfect solution for all browsers but might be enough for your needs.

```html
<input id="date" type="date">
<label for="date">
  <span class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1">icon</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Almost, but in this case you are focusing the date input; what I'm trying to figure out is the way to launch the date picker as if I had clicked the black arrow when clicking the font awesome.

Comment: @JulioRodríguez it does open the datepicker on most browsers except Chrome.