# How to open HTML calendar automatically on page load in Angular without jquery

Tags: html, angular

I have used HTML input with the date field in the Angular application.I would like to open the date field modal on page load based on a condition without using jquery.
The condition is when the input is having a date selected then the calendar shouldn't be opened and if there is no date selected then the dropdown should be opened.

I have tried setting onLoad in the HTML tag but i'm not sure how to close/open the calendar modal.

```
<input
  [class.is-invalid]="deliveryDate.invalid && deliveryDate.touched"
  type="date"
  class="form-control"
  [ngClass]="{'alerts-border': isDateSelected()}"
  [min]="cartItems.minDeliveryDate"
  formControlName="delivery_date"
  onkeydown="return false"
/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975667/html-input-type-date-open-calendar-by-default
is this the one you are searching for?

Comment: @sojin webshim is no longer getting maintained right?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29843310/9239611), the datepicker element is a kind of a separate window and it seems that you cannot call it directly.

So the answer is: no you cannot open the datepicker. If you have angular material installed then you can try their datepciekr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you could try this:

```
<input
  [class.is-invalid]="deliveryDate.invalid && deliveryDate.touched"
  type="date"
  class="form-control"
  [ngClass]="{'alerts-border': isDateSelected()}"
  [min]="cartItems.minDeliveryDate"
  formControlName="delivery_date"
  [disabled]="form.value.delivery_date != null ? true : false"
  onkeydown="return false"
/>
```

**NOTE**: You didn't say the name of your form, I've put **form** as name ([disabled]="**form**.value...).
If your form has another name chage "**form**" by it.

When you initialize the **delivery_date** field, you should initialize it to *null* if you want users could pick a date (or with a string like "2021-11-23" if you want to show the date but not let the user pick another one).

**EXTRA**: When you get the "idea", if it is that you wanted, you have to know that you can even handle the *disability* of the input with the *formControlName="delivery_date"* programmatically (in your *.ts* code), like this:

```
// To disable
this.form.get('delivery_dat').disable();
// to enable
this.form.get('delivery_dat').enable();

// so you can do things like:
if (this.form.get('delivery_dat') != null) {
   this.form.get('delivery_dat').disable();
} else {
   this.form.get('delivery_dat').enable();
}
```